# problem with Simple linear regression

Tags: linear-regression

I am solving a question with

$$x_i = \{1.14,  2.23,  3.01,  4.55\}$$

$$y_i = \{10.77, 7.23, 5.31, 2.84\}$$ and to find out the best fit line of it.

mean of $x_i = 2.73$
mean of $y_i = 6.54$

and the $s_{xx}$ of it is $6.174$ after calculating
but then i find out $s_{xy}$ is a negative number.

So is it normal and should i keep solving the question with $s_{xy}$ is a negative number?

Please help.

Comment: If your $s_{xy}=\sum x_iy_i$, it shouldn't be a negative number.

Comment: @KittyL My lecture note shows Sxy = ∑xiyi -  (∑x)( ∑y) /n

Comment: I see. Then it is not a problem. You can continue solving it.

Comment: thanks Kitty, that really confuses me.